# How Do I Further Specify Range?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, automation, export

I am new to programming.  I want to export an Access query into a specific location in an existing Excel workbook using VBA code in Access.  The following DoCmd object gets me most of the way there, but I am having trouble with specifying the range further:

TransferSpreadsheet(TransferType, SpreadsheetType, TableName, FileName, HasFieldNames, Range, UseOA)

Right now I specify "raw_data" for the worksheet I want Access to paste the query to.  This works if there isn't already a worksheet by that name, but I want to further tell Excel to overwrite it if the worksheet name already exists.

Comment: You may have to do a check beforehand for the worksheet name. If it's present, then have the code select a different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of exporting the query go to excel's data tab and select "Get External Data" and build the linked table.  From here you can use a public function either in the Access DB or in Excel to refresh and do whatever else you need done.

Alternatively here is some code you can use to export from access to excel:

```
Private Sub excelReport(criteria() As String, reportNumber As Integer,  Optional rstINTL As DAO.Recordset, Optional INTLHQ)

   Dim xlApp As Object
   Dim xlWb As Object
   Dim xlWs As Object


   Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   '''switch reference upon emplimintation'''
   Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\USER\FileLocation\" & reportNumber & ".xlt")

   xlApp.Visible = True

   Set xlWs = xlWb.Sheets("Data")
   xlWs.Cells(2, 1).copyfromrecordset Me.RecordsetClone 'result of a query

   End Sub
```